# Можно ли модифицировать padding байты?

Tags: c++, c, language-lawyer

Например:

```cpp
struct A {
  char x;
  int y;
} a{1, 2}, b = a;

int main() {
  reinterpret_cast<unsigned char*>(&a)[1] = 2;
}
```

Легально ли это? И останется ли `b` равным `a`?

Comment: А кто **гарантирует** наличие выравнивания?..

Comment: @Harry имеется в виду дефолтный случай когда char = 1 а int = 4. Тогда оно должно быть.

Answer (score 2):

Компиляторы не обязаны выполнять никакие осмысленные действия, если вы выполняете код с "неопределённым" эффектом. Они даже могут выполнить разные действия при разных опциях компиляции.

> Compilers are not required to diagnose undefined behavior (although many simple situations are diagnosed), and the compiled program is not required to do anything meaningful.

> Компиляторы не обязаны диагностировать неопределенное поведение (хотя диагностируются многие простые ситуации), и от скомпилированной программы не требуется делать что-либо значимое.

[Undefined behavior](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub)

По-поводу заполняющих байтов, компилятор может сам их использовать по своему усмотрению. Например размерами массива или кодом класса с виртуальными функциями.

Comment: ¿На чем базируется уверенность, что тут имеет место Undefined behavior?

Comment: @user7860670 .. попытка взятия значения одного типа по указателю другого. [Расставим точки над структурами C/C++](https://habr.com/ru/articles/142662/)

Comment: Доступ к содержимому любого объекта через указатель на `char`, `unsigned char`, или `std::byte` корректен. А для целочисленных типом еще разрешен доступ через указатель на соотв. тип с противоположным знаком. см **[basic.lval]**

Comment: разговор был про лишние байты. и b может стать не равным a. https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/o6d313ea7 @user7860670

Comment: .. а если ещё вспомнить про little , big endian , то может быть очень странный результат из другой архитектуры. @user7860670

Comment: *"разговор был про лишние байты."* - тогда еще раз: ¿На чем базируется уверенность, что тут имеет место Undefined behavior? Вот ОП сделал объект trivially-copyable класса, стандарт прямо разрешает записывать во все его байты, как минимум, при копировании из другого аналогичного объекта. По идее `memset` и т.п. тоже должно быть легально.

Comment: стандарт говорит, что тип `char` должен быть размером минимум 1 байт, а тип `int` минимум 2 байта. Это значит, что в зависимости от архитектуры, компилятора и его настроек обращение к памяти `reinterpret_cast<unsigned char*>(&a)[1]=3;` может поменять, а может нет, элемент структуры `a.y`. Например, если тип `char` имеет размер 2 байта или структура сжата без выравнивания. @user7860670

Comment: Понятно, что паддинга может и не быть, но вопрос про тот случай, когда он **есть**. `memcpy` пишет в паддинг, `std::ifstream` в бинарном режиме пишет в паддинг (если читать всю структуру целиком из файла). Разрешено ли нам явно писать в паддинг? P.S. Стандарт говорит, что `char` всегда ровно один байт, а `int` минимум `16` бит, но байтов может занимать любое количество, например, `1`.

Comment: @wololo к сожалению, формально в C++20 даже чтение из _object representation_ (все байты класса, включая паддинг) является UB, см. [P1839](https://wg21.link/p1839).

Answer (score 0):

Сначала немного определений.

Для объекта типа `T` существуют "представление объекта" (*object representation*), которое является последовательностью из N `unsigned char` объектов, где `N == sizeof(T)`, и "представление значения" (*value representation*) - множество бит, которое участвует в представлении значения типа `T`. Биты в представлении объекта, которые не являются частью представления значения, называются "заполняющими битами" (*padding bits*).

Для тривиально копируемых типов "представление значения" - это набор битов из представления объекта, определяющих *значение*, которое является одним дискретным элементом из набора значений, определяемых реализацией (*implementation-defined*). Это делает модель памяти C++ совместимой с языком C.

Т.о. если модификация объекта затрагивает исключительно заполняющие биты и не затрагивает биты представления значения, то именованые члены-данные `x` и `y` сохранят свои значения. Говорить о том, будет ли `a == b` истиной можно лишь в том случае, если для `struct A` определён `operator==`. В текущем случае он не определён, но если сравнивать почленно, то их можно рассматривать как равные.